# What defines an item price in an open world survival game?

Tags: economy

Imagine a game like S.T.A.L.K.E.R. -- there are different items that you collect, sell, and buy. Most of them are infinitely renewable via spawning wandering NPCs or via static traders. Defining prices within a class is trivial (a bigger gun costs more) but how do you compare a gun and food?
If you base it on "can you survive without it?" then you can survive without a gun if you just don't fight and spare time in a secured location like a town, but without food you are guaranteed to die in a week. That makes food cost more than a gun that is intuitively wrong.
If you base it on "how many items of the class the world has?" then it's not really possible to compare the number of guns and the number of... calories? Also, there can be some rare but useless/non-functional item class.

Comment: As an aside, you may find [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j3ZqIk5SE7g) (English subtitles) to be very interesting in terms of the value of things in  a SHTF, life or death situation. Things may not be valued as you or I may suspect. Market may depend on momentary shortages / circumstances OR general supply and demand. For example, if a hostile force is known to be headed into town by the next morning, ammo prices will skyrocket the night before. What a person / group knows and how soon they know it, may well be the difference between survival and demise.